# Custom login page with Auth.js and SvelteKit - am I doing this right?

Tags: authentication, svelte, sveltekit, next-auth

I'm using Auth.js for authentication on the SvelteKit app. The auth method is a magic-link email.

In the [docs on custom sign in pages](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/pages#email-sign-in), they mention that you can use the `signIn()` function on the custom login / signup page which will "handle obtaining the CRSF token for you."

So basically, I've just imported the `signIn` function in my `+page.svelte` for the custom sign in page, created an input that binds to a value, and assigned a function on my button that will do some validation and run the `signIn()` function after the checks.

```
signIn('email', { email: userEmail });
```

Is this correct? Does this leave me open to any security vulnerabilities? I assume it's OK as the `signIn()` function is used in other examples client side, but they don't have any docs specifically for custom sign in pages as they relate to SvelteKit.